# PropertyAction doesn't work with an "AnchorChanges" element

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

This is a test showing my problem:

```
Window {
visible: true;width: 360;height: 360

MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: container.state = (container.state=="estado1"?"estado2":"estado1")
}

Rectangle {
    id: container
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "red"
    state: "estado1"
    onStateChanged:console.log("state -> "+state)

    Rectangle {
        id: prueba
        anchors.left: parent.left
        height: 100
        color: "blue"
        onWidthChanged:console.log("width -> "+width)
        onHeightChanged:console.log("height -> "+height)
        onOpacityChanged:console.log("opacity -> "+opacity)
        onYChanged: console.log("coordY -> "+y)

    }
    states: [
        State {
            name: "estado1"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: prueba
                width: 300
                opacity: 1
            }
            AnchorChanges {
                target: prueba
                anchors.bottom: container.bottom
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "estado2"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: prueba
                width: 50
                opacity: 0.5
            }
            AnchorChanges {
                target: prueba
                anchors.top: container.top
            }
        }
    ]
    transitions:[
        Transition {
            ParallelAnimation {
                PropertyAnimation {
                    target: prueba
                    properties: "width"
                    duration: 3000
                }
                PropertyAction {
                    target: prueba
                    property: "opacity"
                }
                /*PropertyAction {
                    target: prueba
                    property: "anchors.top" //doesn't work
                    //property: "anchors" //doesn't work neither
                }*/
                AnchorAnimation {
                    //works, but doesn't seem to be the most
                    //elegant solution to the problem
                    duration: 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Here, you can see an item with two States, changing several properties with `PropertyChanges`, and also an `AnchorChanges`. Also, a `Transition` is defined to control the state change. In that transition, the `width` property is animated with a `PropertyChanges` element, and the `opacity` is changed at the beginning of the transition without animations, with a `PropertyAction`.

The problem is that i would like to change also the anchor without animations. But, if i try to use a `PropertyAction`, it doesn't work. 
I can use an animation with duration 0, but i don't think this is the correct approach. Is there any problem with the syntax, or maybe another approach must be used?

Comment: It should work with `PropertyAction`. As described in [PropertyAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyaction.html) Detailed description you should put `PropertyAction` before animation. But for me that still not works. It works without problem if you play with some other properties, for example `y` but not with `anchors.top`. So may be the problem is defining the `anchor` property in some right way?

Comment: don't you think that the problem may be the anchor type itself? i've seen lot of examples of `PropertyAction` being applied on a numeric property (that is changed in the State definition using a `PropertyChanges`), but none with a more complex property.

Comment: It works not with only numeric values, for example `color` works fine. But yes, may be you're right and that doesn't work with composite properties. For me that looks a bug, Any way I've asked that in Qt mailing list, maybe someone from pro guys could answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked Qt support and here is what they say:

> The reason this is happening is because the anchor is being dealt with
>   differently and not as a property animation. What you need to do is
>   use the AnchorAnimation instead and set a duration for it so that it
>   does the move at the rate you want. If you want the anchor change to
>   have an effect right away then you can do:
>
> ```
> AnchorAnimation { 
>     duration: 1  
> }
> ```
>
> and it will instantly move first before the rest of the animation takes place.

The answer is: your approach is *correct*. There is no simple way to omit using `AnchorAnimation`.

Comment: mmmmh, i thought the problem was me and unknowledge of the correct approach, but there is no approach as correct as the `PropertyAction`. So that, i will keep using the animation, maybe changing the duration from 0 to 1 (i suppose they said 1 because is better than 0). Thanks a lot, @Mertanian, and also @folibis, for your interest. By the way, is this "Qt support" public? how can i solve this kind of doubts apart from qt forum, and qt mailing list of [Qt project](http://qt.io) ?

Comment: @AlbertoJiménez Unfortunately Qt Support is available only if you have commercial Qt license. Apart from qt forum you can ask here. The community can be very helpful. Also (as far as I know) you can let Qt know about found bugs and it is available for everyone

Comment: yes, i know they have a bug report system [here](https://bugreports.qt.io). I supposed that support was only for commercial license. Thanks a lot for your help.